# Git pull from production server without direct server access

Tags: git, git-pull

We've been granted access for development to a client's remote repository (`CodebaseHQ`) but due to an entry in `.gitignore`, there is a directory that does not exist in the remote repo.

I've modified the `.gitignore` (removing the necessary entry) and pushed this to the remote repo but is there anyway I can now pull this directory from the live server into the repo?

I don't have direct access to the server. I push the local repo to the remote repo on `codebasehq` and we deploy to the production server using `deployhq`.

### Edit

As there is a vote to close this, I shall clarify my question.

There is a directory that exists on the live server but doesn't exist in the repository on `codebasehq`. How can I get this directory from the server into the repository (it has been removed from `.gitignore`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't. Pushing in an updated `.gitignore` means that if the code is now pulled from the repo into the live server, the directory would be visible there if you do `git status`. Nothing more.

You will still need to access that server in order to make a commit from there adding the directory, and to push the changes back to the repo, from where they can be pulled downstream later.

So you should request the client to

1. either provide you with that directory
2. or run the commit and push steps on the server himself
3. or provide you temporary access to the live server so that you can commit and push

PS: It is generally not recommended to make commits from the server, but given the exceptional circumstances, you can do that.

Comment: I was worried that would be the case, thank you for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

Well, remove directory from `.gitignore`, then check if you have files inside this directory in the local rep. If true, `commit` and `push` them to remote rep.
If no, but you know the files are in the remote rep, then you need push `.gitignore` file without the folder, and commit changes from remote rep.

If no files in any repo, you need to add to the project again.